# AN EXAMPLE OF EXTREMUM VALUES OF FUNCTION FROM Thomas Calculus

Tags: calculus, analysis

[image]

The picture is from Thomas Calculus 12th Ed. In the answers it says that the point $(2,1)$ is a local maximum point of the function $f$ which is correct to me because $f(2)\geq f(x)$ for some open interval containing $2$. But when we check the sign of the first derivative, it does not change at $2$, it is positive either side of the point $2$ and the book says "if the derivative's sign does not change, then the point itself fails to be a local extremum" consequently, $x=2$ is local maximum point as the definition of local maximum point and is not since derivative's sign does not change at $x=2$. I am so confused, any hint or help will greatly be aprreciated.  Should we assume that x=2
is an end-point of the left function?  the book says "A function ƒ has a local maximum value at a point c within its
domain D if $ƒ(x)\leqƒ(c)$ for all $x\in D$ lying in some open interval containing c." so $x=2$ is an end-point for the left function

Comment: There are assumptions on the first derivative test.  This function doesn't meet them.  The version I know needs $f$ to be continuous around the point of interest.

Comment: See, for instance, here:  https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408n/CurrentWeb/LM4-3-5.php

Comment: I think the thing to do is make sure that you understand why this is a local max *straight from the definition* with no influence from the derivative.  Next, understand why this does NOT contradict the first derivative test.

Comment: I completely understood it, first derivative test are for ones that are continuous. so the definition here says it is a local extremum. and We can not take the derivative test into consideration since the function is not continuous? @Randall

Comment: The first derivative test says that if a point is a local maximum and it is differentiable at that point, then the derivative is zero. In this case, the function is not differentiable at $x=2$ so the test doesn't apply.

Comment: @JohnDouma there are versions of the FDT that allow for points of nondifferentiability, but must still require continuity.  This is why the definition of critical point allows for $f'(a)$ to be nonexistent, such as in $|x|$ at $0$ (but which still has a local min there that is spotted by the FDT).

Comment: @Woodx your last comment is exactly right.  Simpler examples help to see the reason continuity is needed:  consider $f(x)=x^2$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=2$.  But yes, you've got the thinking exactly right now.

Comment: @Woodx I think you should write up your own answer now.

Comment: So My question is completed well. I clearly understood that the difference of it. Thank you very much. @Randall

Answer (score 2):

The derivative is not defined at this point. Probably the statement in your book is assuming that the function is continuously differentiable.

Comment: or Should we assume that $x=2$ is an end-point of the left function?

Comment: the book says "A function ƒ has a local maximum value at a point c within its
domain D if $ƒ(x)\leqƒ(c)$ for all $x\in D$ lying in some open interval containing c." so $x=2$ is an end-point for the left function

Comment: The way to see it is the following: the definition of local maximum using a neighborhood is correct. This is necessary and sufficient condition. THEN, in the special case where your function is also continuously differentiable, you have a different condition you can check, that will be equivalent to the original definition, using the sign of the derivative changing.

Comment: Given the domain of this function, $x=2$ is not an "endpoint" and analyzing as if it were will give wrong conclusions.  @Woodx

Comment: Yes I understood it now, discontinuity part confused me, continuously differentiable is the key @JürgenSukumaran